# Why isset and not empty doesn't work in this Solarium object iteration

Tags: php, object, if-statement

I'm trying to iterate the below object using foreach in PHP but I don't get any result.

```
 Solarium\QueryType\Select\Result\Document Object
(
    [fields:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3007WFP
            [name] => Dell Widescreen UltraSharp 3007WFP
            [manu] => Dell, Inc.
            [manu_id_s] => dell
            [cat] => Array
                (
                    [0] => electronics and computer1
                )

            [features] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 30" TFT active matrix LCD, 2560 x 1600, .25mm dot pitch, 700:1 contrast
                )

            [includes] => USB cable
            [weight] => 401.6
            [price] => 2199
            [price_c] => 2199,USD
            [popularity] => 6
            [inStock] => 1
            [store] => 43.17614,-90.57341
            [_version_] => 1.485082319029E+18
            [score] => 1
        )

)

Solarium\QueryType\Select\Result\Document Object
(
    [fields:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => book2
            [cat] => Array
                (
                    [0] => fantasy
                )

            [pubyear_i] => 1996
            [title] => Array
                (
                    [0] => A Game of Thrones
                )

            [author] => George R.R. Martin
            [author_s] => George R.R. Martin
            [series_s] => A Song of Ice and Fire
            [sequence_i] => 1
            [_version_] => 1.4850828331521E+18
            [score] => 1
        )

)

Solarium\QueryType\Select\Result\Document Object
(
    [fields:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => book3
            [cat] => Array
                (
                    [0] => fantasy
                )

            [pubyear_i] => 1999
            [title] => Array
                (
                    [0] => A Clash of Kings
                )

            [author] => George R.R. Martin
            [author_s] => George R.R. Martin
            [series_s] => A Song of Ice and Fire
            [sequence_i] => 2
            [_version_] => 1.4850828331574E+18
            [score] => 1
        )

)

Solarium\QueryType\Select\Result\Document Object
(
    [fields:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => book4
            [cat] => Array
                (
                    [0] => sci-fi
                )

            [pubyear_i] => 1951
            [title] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Foundation
                )

            [author] => Isaac Asimov
            [author_s] => Isaac Asimov
            [series_s] => Foundation Series
            [sequence_i] => 1
            [_version_] => 1.4850828331584E+18
            [score] => 1
        )

)

Solarium\QueryType\Select\Result\Document Object
(
    [fields:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => book5
            [cat] => Array
                (
                    [0] => sci-fi
                )

            [pubyear_i] => 1952
            [title] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Foundation and Empire
                )

            [author] => Isaac Asimov
            [author_s] => Isaac Asimov
            [series_s] => Foundation Series
            [sequence_i] => 2
            [_version_] => 1.4850828331605E+18
            [score] => 1
        )

)

Solarium\QueryType\Select\Result\Document Object
(
    [fields:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => book6
            [cat] => Array
                (
                    [0] => sci-fi
                )

            [pubyear_i] => 1992
            [title] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Snow Crash
                )

            [author] => Neal Stephenson
            [author_s] => Neal Stephenson
            [series_s] => Snow Crash
            [_version_] => 1.4850828331616E+18
            [score] => 1
        )

)

Solarium\QueryType\Select\Result\Document Object
(
    [fields:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => book7
            [cat] => Array
                (
                    [0] => sci-fi
                )

            [pubyear_i] => 1984
            [title] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Neuromancer
                )

            [author] => William Gibson
            [author_s] => William Gibson
            [series_s] => Sprawl trilogy
            [sequence_i] => 1
            [_version_] => 1.4850828331636E+18
            [score] => 1
        )

)

Solarium\QueryType\Select\Result\Document Object
(
    [fields:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => book8
            [cat] => Array
                (
                    [0] => fantasy
                )

            [pubyear_i] => 1985
            [title] => Array
                (
                    [0] => The Black Company
                )

            [author] => Glen Cook
            [author_s] => Glen Cook
            [series_s] => The Black Company
            [sequence_i] => 1
            [_version_] => 1.4850828331647E+18
            [score] => 1
        )

)

Solarium\QueryType\Select\Result\Document Object
(
    [fields:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => book9
            [cat] => Array
                (
                    [0] => fantasy
                )

            [pubyear_i] => 1965
            [title] => Array
                (
                    [0] => The Black Cauldron
                )

            [author] => Lloyd Alexander
            [author_s] => Lloyd Alexander
            [series_s] => The Chronicles of Prydain
            [sequence_i] => 2
            [_version_] => 1.4850828331657E+18
            [score] => 1
        )

)

Solarium\QueryType\Select\Result\Document Object
(
    [fields:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Getting Started with Solr, a simple Solr Tutorial
                )

            [description] => The Unofficial Solr Guide: This simple Solr Tutorial covers basic Heliosearch and Apache Solr installation, Solr indexing, Solr search and querying.
            [keywords] => solr,tutorial,guide,covers,indexing,search,query,installation,unofficial,apache
            [url] => http://heliosearch.org/solr/getting-started/
            [_version_] => 1.4850885076533E+18
            [score] => 1
        )

)
```

I'm using the following PHP code

```
<?php 
            if($this->totalResults > 0) {
                foreach($this->results as $result) {
                    //if(!empty($result->title) && !empty($result->url) && !empty($result->description)) {
                    if(isset($result->title) && isset($result->url) && isset($result->description)) {
            ?>
                <div class="search_result">
                    <a class="title" href="#">
                        <?php echo $result->title[0];?>
                    </a><br/>
                    <span class="url">
                        <?php echo $result->url;?>
                    </span><br/>
                    <span class="description">
                        <?php echo $result->description;?>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <?php }
                    }
                }?>
```

I never get any result but I should get the last node because it contains title, url and description keys.

But when I simply put

```
if($result->title && $result->url && $result->description) {
```

Then it works fine. Why is it not working in that mode.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Let me tell you that isset works only on variables and not for objects. Please read the documentation on php.net http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php. I would recommend reading the example at the bottom of the page where it has been explained how isset always returns false when we pass an object to it.

Comment: but I've mentioned in the question that !empty is also not working. Then what about that???

Comment: If the field is not there then how it will check for an empty string? Think about it.

Comment: Try converting the object into array using (array)($phpObj) then isset and !empty will start working. If you find the answer useful then you can tick it...:)

Comment: See the screenshot please

Comment: The screenshot of the post you have posted is six years old. The properties of the isset function has been changed. What is the php version you are using? I would also recommend using magic method __isset(). Hope this helps, I am also learning with you :)

Comment: Could you give me any latest example of this?

Answer (score 0):

Because those properties are existent, but filled with an empty string or null... so `isset()` is always true for them... if you are not 100% sure, that they are always there, you could combine both checks `(isset($result->title) && $result->title)`. The alternative would be something like `(isset($result->title) && !empty($result->title))`, which should work too

Comment: I'm editing the question and posting the whole object